# Shared memory SIGSEGV segmentation fault on access in C?

Tags: linux, gcc

I have server program that create 4 shared memory segments of different size.
The client program get attached to the created segments but on strcmp the shared memory variable gives segmentation violation.

checked through ipcs..
I've been trying this for hours, and google all the things I kind think of, but not getting solution.
Here's some debug results...

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x009aeb87 in __strcmp_sse4_2 () from /lib/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686    libX11-1.3-2.el6.i686 libXau-1.0.5-1.el6.i686 libxcb-1.5-1.el6.i686
(gdb) bt
0  0x009aeb87 in __strcmp_sse4_2 () from /lib/libc.so.6
1  0x0809f242 in isSymb (inName=0x80aa485 "SimTime")
at /usr2/ptask5/TICSS/src/mdsm/dsm/xsymbol.c:178
(gdb) down
1  0x0809f242 in isSymb (inName=0x80aa485 "SimTime")
at /usr2/ptask5/TICSS/src/mdsm/dsm/xsymbol.c:178
if ( !strcmp( sp->symbName, inName ) )
(gdb) p inName
$1 = 0x80aa485 "SimTime"
(gdb) p sp->symbName
$2 = 0x0
```

The sp->symbName reads as 0x0 hence the fault occurs... found during debugging..but don't know how to fix...pls help

Comment: It is your code, only you could tell why it is 0. And this is exactly the reason of segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set breakpoints (or `printf`s or `assert`s) at the places where `sp->symbName` is set to a value and make sure it's never assigned `NULL` plus that it's assigned a value at all.